# Import Error of Flask Application in IDLE console

Tags: python, flask, python-idle

I want to import a Flask object into IDLE so that I can experiment and explore.

I am able to launch an interactive command line session successfully by typing `python` from the project directory.

```
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov 18 2019, 00:27:11)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from app import app
>>> dir(app)
['Flask', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', 
'__package__', '__spec__', 'app', 'create_app', 'current_app', 'index', 'make_response', 'randint']
>>> exit()
```

But I want to use IDLE for this exploration.
So I added my project path to `sys.path` in IDLE.
When I try to import using `from app import app`, I get the error `AttributeError: module 'config' has no attribute 'settings`.

The code sample:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__,instance_relative_config=True)

    app.config.from_object('config.settings')
    app.config.from_pyfile('settings.py',silent=True)

    return app
```

Project structure:

```
project_dir/
   ├── app/
   │   ├── app.py
   ├── config/
   │   │                                                                                                                                                                                
   │   └── settings.py                                                                                                                                                                                               
   └── instance/                                                                                                                                                                                                          
       └── settings.py
```

Why is IDLE unable to find the `settings.py` module in the `config` directory?

NOTE: When I remove the line `app.config.from_object('config.settings')`, the import succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

IDLE only finds files when you use the IDLE open command to edit a file.  When you ask IDLE to execute your code, it calls compile() and passes the result to the executing python.

`app.config.from_object('config.settings')` fails for the reason given in the error message: the `config` object has no attribute `settings`.  Adding `import config.settings` may fix this.  I cannot be sure because your project structure diagram is ambiguous.  It shows `config` as both a top-level directory, parallel to `app` and `instance` and as a subdirectory of `app`.

Comment: Thank you. 
"It shows `config` as both a top-level directory, parallel to `app` and ``instance". YES
"...and as a subdirectory of `app`" NO.

`config` is in the same directory as `instance` and `app`. They all have the same parent directory.

Please note that, as mentioned, invoking `python` from this parent directory works fine.

Is there a specific clarification I can add to the question to make this clearer? 
I have updated the project structure to add this parent directory.